# Trying to add floating image and and description in a filled box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this to happen.
[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uoRx.png)

So far, I don't know how to overlap one img-div with another text-div and keep white space on the top of the text-div. You will see. What I have right now is:

```
<div id="some">
    <img src="photos/some.png">
    <div id="box">
        <p>Proudly seeking</p>
        <h2>some Cofefe</h2>
        <button id="shopNow" class="button">Shop</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

With some CSS that doesn't make it very appealing: [what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUf7R.jpg)

```
#some{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
#some img{

    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
#box{
    padding-top: 220px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-family: "Eusthalia";
    text-align: right;
}
#box p{
 margin-right: 32%   
}
h2 {
    font-size: 2.6em;
}
button {
    border: none;
    font-family: "Eusthalia";
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #300c06;
    color: #eadfc0;
    padding: 2px 10px;

}
```

I am wondering if my whole approach with divs is wrong. I was researching and I found that right:0; doesn't work and stuff like that. How do I get a border to overlap behind the image? How do I give it a width and a height but make it push to the right?

Do I have to make the main div width 100% and then give the img a width 30% and the colored filled in text box 70%? But how would I have the box behind the img?

Comment: Have you tried `position: absolute` for img?

Answer (score 0):

Drearo, I think you're doing fine with div tags. You just may need a bit more of them to help things along.

I would suggest the divs be position: absolute with the image in one of those. The box of text needs it too. Aside from that, a little CSS would get you the positioning you want. See here:

```
<div id="some">
   <div class="my_img">
   <img src="photos/some.jpg" />
</div>
        <div id="box">
            <p>Proudly seeking</p>
            <h2>some Cofefe</h2>
            <button id="shopNow" class="button">Shop</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#some{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.my_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  left: 5em;
  z-index: 200;

}
.my_img img {
  width: 200px;
}
#box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10em;
    left: 10em;
    transition: translate( -50%, -50%);
    font-family: "Eusthalia";
    text-align: right;
    background: red;
    min-width: 60%;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
#box p{
 margin-right: 32%   
}
h2 {
    font-size: 2.6em;
}
button {
    border: none;
    font-family: "Eusthalia";
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #300c06;
    color: #eadfc0;
    padding: 2px 10px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5k94j73p/

Comment: Hey Kummer, I was wondering we're using top 10em? Is there no way to keep it inside the box? I have to do about 100em for it to reach where the picture is placed. Also, when resizing the page the img is completely infront of the text so I can't see it. Is there a way to solve this without @media ?

Comment: Oh sure. You would use a position:relative on the outer box. That allows you to have control over any children in the box that are a position:absolute. It also will contain your position:absolute.

Because you want your image to float over a portion of the box with the text, you're still stuck with either a top and left with positioning ( either via emphasis or a % for left and top ).

Which gets us to the media queries. Yes, when you resize ( such as with the browser or viewing the page on a phone or tablet ) you'll need to possibly use some media queries to control this.

Comment: Oh, and the 10em? that was just adding some position for the image. You'll need to add the value you need for the image / layout you want to achieve.